# Hapi Lab why Test failed when all the tests are passed

Tags: hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

Does anyone know the meaning of ?

> npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

```
3 tests complete
Test duration: 873 ms
The following leaks were detected:lr

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I run my 3 tests I get 
a successful green 3 tests complete
(all my test are passed)
but why I also see the nasty ?

> > npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The test fails because `lab` detected a global variable leak:

> The following leaks were detected:lr

This means you probably defined the `lr` variable somewhere as global. Try to find where you did that and make the variable local. The other option is to run `lab` with the [`-l`](https://github.com/hapijs/lab#command-line) option which disables global variable leak detection (it is not recommended though).

Comment: A module can define it too. I don't know which modules you use, but "lr" can stand for "live reload". If `lr` is defined in a module, you can use the `-I` (`--ignore`) option of lab to ignore that variable.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by deleting my node_modules folder and running "npm install" again since my major versions of both node & npm had changed.